# Redshift deadlocking on a single table

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm writing an ETL process in redshift and I would really like for it to be more parallelizable. The process creates a bunch of temporary tables, and then merges them together into the main table, inside a transaction that looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table
    (LIKE production_table);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
LOCK TABLE production_table;

/* Dedupe and then insert */
DELETE FROM temporary_table
   USING production_table
   WHERE temporary_table.id = production_table.id
       AND temporary_table.date <= production_table.date;

INSERT INTO production_table
SELECT * FROM temporary_table;

END TRANSACTION;
```

I expect the `LOCK TABLE production_table;` query to block until any other transactions finish, but whenever I try to run this in practice, I get:

```
ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL: Process 4868 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 165643 of database 154587; blocked by process 4863.
    Process 4863 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 165643 of database 154587; blocked by process 4868.
```

This happens between the two delete/insert statements. Why does the lock table step not prevent deadlocks? How can I structure my writes so that they block until the other transaction is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured this out.

There is an implicit lock on `production_table` whenever you do

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table
    (LIKE production_table)
```

for the lifetime of the temporary table. I used the actual schema of the production table in the create temporary table query, and the deadlocks went away.

Comment: This is such an ugly solution. I hope that there is or will be a better solution. But so far this is the best solution I could find.

Comment: @hans-z, can you please elaborate about the cause of the deadlock ? There is still  **single** resource  involved (`production_table`), and the deadlock  usually happens when you  lock **several resources**  out of order...

Comment: Is it because  the lock is per **query** and not per **session**? and that's why `re-enrtancy` is lost ?

Comment: @Alexander.Furer the lock on `production_table` when you do `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table (LIKE production_table)` is **in a separate process**. That lock can't release while `temporary_table` exists, and the query that deletes `temporary_table` can't run until the query `LOCK TABLE production_table;` runs, which results in a deadlock.

Comment: Had the same problem, here. Guessing most everybody here has multiple worker jobs running batch import and referenced the Amazon guidelines for upserts in Redshift at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html.

Another, less visually messy option is to throw
```CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table
    (LIKE production_table);```
in the same block as the deletion/insertion to the production_table.

The cost is all actions occur in sequence, and there is no opportunity for parallelization.